# tcsh, save command in a history, only if the command was successful

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

I'm new to `tcsh` so please advice me. Now I use `postcmd` variable to save history:

```
alias postcmd "history -S; history -M;"
```

The problem is, it saves almost everything I type to terminal. I want to filter out some misspelled commands, or, for example, commands that returned some non-zero status. My first try is this:

```
alias postcmd "if ($? == 0) history -S; history -M;"
```

But the above, still saves all misspelled commands and commands with non-zero exit status.
The question is, how to make `tcsh` to filter out as much unappropriate commands as possible?

*** update ***

I have no clue how to make `tcsh` history to behave as I want it to, so I leave a note for myself here. What I did is

```
set history = 0
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set savehist = (3000 merge lock)
alias precmd 'if($? == 0) history -S; history -c; history -M'
```

then

```
tcsh% true
tcsh% false
tcsh% false
tcsh% true
tcsh% history
    20  0:15    true
    21  0:16    true
    22  0:16    history
```

#### Why the `history -c`?

It clears the history; otherwise failing / misspelled commands will still be added to the current (in-memory) history, and a subsequent `history -S` will save them, even if only invoked after a successful command.

Notice that in `if(..) cmd1; cmd2; cmd3` `cmd2` and `cmd3` will be run unconditionally.

#### Why `precmd` instead of `postcmd`?

```
tcsh% alias postcmd 'echo postcmd = $?'
tcsh% alias precmd 'echo precmd = $?'
postcmd = 0
precmd = 0
tcsh% false
postcmd = 0
precmd = 1
```

---

#### Does an intermediate alias work to group the commands?

No, because the command after `if (...)` can't be an alias:

```
tcsh% alias ok 'echo ok'
tcsh% ok
ok
tcsh% if (1) ok
ok: Command not found.
```

From the `tcsh(1)` manpage:

> `if (expr) command`
>
> ... `command` must  be  a  simple  command,  **not  an
>                  alias**,  a  pipeline,  a command list or a parenthesized command
>                  list, but it may have arguments

#### Why not use a multiline alias with `precmd` or `postcmd`?

Because it will invoke itself recursively:

```
tcsh% alias postcmd 'if ($? == 0) then\
echo OK\
endif\
'
OK
OK
<ad nauseam>
^C
```

Comment: let me check, and thanks a lot for taking your time to make such a complete answer.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко the `lock` in `savehist` may not work right over nfs -- or maybe it was just a mess up on my side.

Comment: Hello. This seems to be the most complete answer I could get by far. Still had no time to make it work in my shell tho. But still, great thanks. I should definetly accept your answer.